# How to make Query array request with Retrofit2?

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to make GET request with this query:

```
.../apartments?category[first][one]=53&category[first][two]=27&category[second][one]=53&category[second][two]=27&order=created_at&page=1
```

I tried to add it like this:

```
    public interface ApiService {

        @GET(SEARCH + CATEGORY)
        Observable<Responce> getResponceObservable(
                @Query("category[first][one]") double var1,
                @Query("category[first][two]") double var2,
                @Query("category[second][one]") double var3,
                @Query("category[second][two]") double var4,
                @Query("order") String order,
                @Query("page") int page
        );
```

But the error on log is as the following:

```
<-- 415 Unsupported Media Type https://base.com/search/categories?category[first][one]=53&category[first][two]=53&category[second][one]=53&category[second][two]=53&order=created_at&page=1 (384ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you send data with @Body:

It will go like this:

```
public class Category {

double category1,category2,category3,category4;
String order;
int page;

public double getCategory1() {
    return category1;
}

public void setCategory1(double category1) {
    this.category1 = category1;
}

public double getCategory2() {
    return category2;
}

public void setCategory2(double category2) {
    this.category2 = category2;
}

public double getCategory3() {
    return category3;
}

public void setCategory3(double category3) {
    this.category3 = category3;
}

public double getCategory4() {
    return category4;
}

public void setCategory4(double category4) {
    this.category4 = category4;
}

public String getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(String order) {
    this.order = order;
}

public int getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(int page) {
    this.page = page;
}
```

}

And To send data do:

```
Category category = new category();
... //Set your data

@GET("apartments")
Call<CategoryResponse> send_data(@Body Category category );
```

See the link below for reference:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body